# Search for key in Nested Json in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below Json.

My requirement is to search this Json and get '**id**' value if '**name**' is equal to 'Latisha Chase'

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d3121cd001453772160a791",
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Mcknight Tran"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Helena Bowers"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Dorsey Ayala"
      }
    ]
    },
  {
"_id": "5d3121cd838efa513e7dda96",
"friends": [ {
  "friends": [
  {
    "id": 90,
    "name": "w Stark"
  },
  {
    "id": 91,
    "name": "w Jacobs"
  },
  {
    "id": 93,
    "name": "w Garner"
  }
]},
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Amalia Stark"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Myra Jacobs"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Norton Garner"
  }
]
}
```

]

This is sample code that I have. Could anyone help me with this.?

I tried recursive codes online but didn't work with my example here.

Update:
Its not necessary that 'friends' will have single depth. it can have friends inside friends. ex: friends [{ friends[ {}]}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general approach using recursion:

```
def recursive_function(name, l):
    if isinstance(l,list):
        for i in l:
            recursive_function(name, i)
    elif isinstance(l,dict):
        if l.get("name") == name:
            print (l.get("id"))
        for v in l.values():
            if isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict):
                recursive_function(name, v)

recursive_function("Latisha Chase",json_obj)
```

Result:

```
3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It didn't work when more than one depth exists. " "friends": [ {
      "friends": [
      {
        "id": 90,
        "name": "w Stark"
      },
      {
        "id": 91,
        "name": "w Jacobs"
      },
      {
        "id": 93,
        "name": "w Garner"
      }
    ]}]

Comment: Can you update in your code in the question? It's hard to see.

Comment: done. I cant paste my original code. so I pasted example code. thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure it works just the same. You didn't format the data into a valid json though so make sure the format is correct before running the function.

Comment: Great. Thank much!

Comment: Hi @HenryYik could you use this recursive function to also change the 'id' as well? Lets say is another bit of info that needs updating. I tried to do some simple `l.get('id') = 'updated_id'` and did not really worked. Am I missing something. I'm new to json files.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
j = [{
    "_id": "5d3121cd001453772160a791",
    "friends": [{
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Mcknight Tran"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Helena Bowers"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Dorsey Ayala"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5d3121cded44d8ba6ad96b78",
    "friends": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "June Gilbert"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Latisha Chase"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Franco Carlson"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5d3121cd838efa513e7dda96",
    "friends": [{
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Amalia Stark"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Myra Jacobs"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Norton Garner"
      }
    ]
  }
]
for x in j:
  for y in x.get('friends'):
    if y.get('name') == 'Latisha Chase':
      print y.get('id')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Its not necessary that Json will have constant depth. it can have multiple 'friends' dicts inside. for ex:  friends [{ friends [{ friends {}[}]}]]

Comment: Then you have iterate with the keys `friends` as you want. I am answering it base on your question input.

Comment: I think i have updated the question now. Could you update the code above. Sorry Im still learning dictionaries in python